# A Question about Chia Proof of Space

Tags: chia

I'm trying to understand how [Chia Proof of Space](https://www.chia.net/assets/proof_of_space.pdf) works by reading docs [here](https://github.com/Chia-Network/chiapos/tree/main/documents).

According to one document, I need to calculate $f(x1) = f2(x1, x2)$ but with the requirement that $f1(x1) == f1(x2) + 1$.

The problem is, $f1$ is not a permutation. How do I handle the $x1$'s for which there is no such $x2$? It seems $f(x1)$ is not defined for about 2/3 of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer. We don't search for the exact match #$f1(x1)==f2(x2)+1$. We just want those values to be as close as possible. However, a bigger difference means a less valuable solution, a lower probability of having a right to sign the block.